# What is the best way to send emails from PHP script? [2]

Tags: php, sendmail, spam-prevention

I hope this question wont be too specific. But I really need to ask. We all know that we cannot fully prevent our emails to go to spam box right? But I guess we can decrease the #of emails that goes there.

Till now, I use PHP's built-in function mail() but I guess there are other methods right? What are they and what is your best practice for this problem?

Taken from: [What is the best practice to send emails from PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994732/what-is-the-best-practice-to-send-emails-from-php-script)
That's over a year old, hence the new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

It's awesome! I've used it in all my projects with great results!

About the mail going to spam, I suggest [this](http://emailmarketing.comm100.com/email-marketing-tutorial/emails-going-to-junk.aspx) article

Comment: Even PHPMailer, it's old but still gold.

Comment: PHPMailer is good, but as you said, old. I don't know about its mantainance but Swiftmailer is actively mantained as well....

Comment: Yep I've used PHPMailer for a while but then I switched to Swift because it's actively maintained

Answer (score 1):

I love PHPMailer and it is now maintained at github. If you want then you could check then go to the page at: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer