# Why is PHP mail function not recommended for sending bulk email?

Tags: php, email, bulk

Could somebody explain to me, why is PHP's mail function not suitable for sending mass emails? I'd like to understand this as deeply as possible - it would be really nice if someone trained in the arcane art of sending email through PHP could explain how all this works. Other online sources are welcome too!

Comment: This SO article might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994732/what-is-the-best-practice-to-send-emails-from-php-script

Comment: See this article by Jeff Atwood. It's not expressly talking about PHP but the concepts are the same. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes):

> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.

The link above specifies 2 alternatives however.

Answer (score 1):

Statement you quote is "imprecise", IMHO it is limited to "out of the box" use.

PHP mail function may be configured to use custom sendmail program wrapper/replacement - see
[sendmail-path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path).

SMTP server (under your control) may used by PHP mail may be fine tuned to handle well bulk submissions (it is server depended).

---

What mass mail means in your case?

- 5_000 customized messages to single recipient each
- one email without content customizations to 20_000 recipients
- ...